# How to validate swapping of webelements?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using below code to swap the webelement:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; left: " + location2.getX() + "px; top: " + location2.getY() + "px;');", element1);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; left: " + location1.getX() + "px; top: " + location1.getY() + "px;');", element2);
```

It's working fine, but problem how to validate swapping done or not? If I use locations using **Point** class then

```
Point location1 = element1.getLocation();
Point location2 = element2.getLocation();
//swapping code placed here
Point newLocation1 = element1.getLocation();
Point newLocation2 = element2.getLocation();
```

Then location1 matches with newLocation2 perfectly but location2 **not matching** with newLocation1 so this `if` condition always fails:

```
if((location1.equals(newLocation2) && (location2.equals(newLocation2)){
    System.Out.Println("Swapping done");
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML, also properly formatted.

Comment: Post the URL, full code you've tried and explain your issue clearly.